# How to make spaces and indentation insignificant in Django blocktrans?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-i18n

Image the following `blocktrans` in some Django template:

```
{% blocktrans %}
    Some Text
{% endblocktrans %}
```

After some changes in the templates, you might like to indent the block:

```
<div>
    {% blocktrans %}
        Some Text
    {% endblocktrans %}
</div>
```

This is going to change your message in the translation files, and mark them as fuzzy. While technically, it is the same message (only the indentation is different).

The whole process of "unfuzzyfying" those messages is tedious and error-prone.

What I tried so far:

- Using `trans` as much as possible - doesn't always work
- Keeping the initial indentation of `blocktrans` statements - hard to maintain
- Tried to find more information in documentation and other resources

Is there a way to make the indentation in `blocktrans` insignificant?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag):

> Another feature {% blocktrans %} supports is the trimmed option. This
>   option will remove newline characters from the beginning and the end
>   of the content of the {% blocktrans %} tag, replace any whitespace at
>   the beginning and end of a line and merge all lines into one using a
>   space character to separate them. This is quite useful for indenting
>   the content of a {% blocktrans %} tag without having the indentation
>   characters end up in the corresponding entry in the PO file, which
>   makes the translation process easier.

so for example

```
<div>
    {% blocktrans trimmed %}
        Some Text
    {% endblocktrans %}
</div>
```

will result in the entry `"Some Text"` in your PO file.